# Restoring the connection to the socket after a page refresh on the client

Tags: javascript, sockets, webpack, websocket

**What I want:**
I use node js. At the moment my project doesn't have any logic, but I need to understand how sockets work.
I have a task list on the client side where I enter the name of the task, the repetition time and the time after which the task will stop.
I need the logs to be displayed both on the client and on the server.
For example, if the user entered:
"Task 1" repeat every 2 minutes and finish in an hour

Then both on the server and on the client in the console of the browser is displayed:

```
| "Task 1" started at 11:00 AM   |
| Completed task "Task 1" at 11:02 AM   |
| Started task "Task 1" at 11:02 AM   |
| Completed task "Task 1" at 11:04 AM   |
| ...  |
| ...  |
| Completed Task 1 task after the time at 12:00 AM  |
```

**What's the problem:**
I've done everything, but the problem remains that if you refresh the site page, the connection to the socket is broken and a new one is created. This causes the new "Task Started" and "Task Completed" messages to not show up in the browser console.

**What I tried to do:**
I found an [official article on my problem](https://socket.io/docs/v4/connection-state-recovery). I seemed to have done everything as it needed to be done, but it didn't help. Refreshing the page still establishes a new connection. No new messages are displayed in the console.

**My code:**
server.js

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {
  connectionStateRecovery: {
    maxDisconnectionDuration: 2 * 60 * 1000,
    skipMiddlewares: true,
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  if (socket.recovered) {
    console.log('Соединение восстановлено:', socket.id);
    // Восстановление состояния сокета
    // Ваш код для обработки восстановленного состояния сокета
  } else {
    console.log('Новое подключение:', socket.id);
    // Ваш код для нового подключения
  }
  

  // Обработчик запуска задачи
  socket.on('startTask', (data) => {
    const { duration, stopAfter, nameTask, userId } = data;

    // Проверка, есть ли уже активная задача для данного пользователя
    if (userTasks[userId]) {
      socket.emit('taskError', { message: `У вас уже есть активная задача ${userTasks[userId]}` });
      console.log(`У вас уже есть активная задача`);
      console.log(userTasks);
      return;
    }
    // Проверка, есть ли уже задача с таким именем для данного пользователя
    if (userTasks[userId] && userTasks[userId][nameTask]) {
      socket.emit('taskError', { message: 'Не возможно запустить ещё одну задачу' });
      return;
    }
    

    const task = {
      id: taskId,
      duration,
      stopAfter,
      nameTask,
      userId,
      startTime: moment(),
      stopTime: moment().add(stopAfter, 'hours'),
    };

    // Добавление задачи в соответствующую структуру данных
    if (!userTasks[userId]) {
      userTasks[userId] = {};
    }
    userTasks[userId][nameTask] = task;
    taskId++;

    console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} запущена ${new Date()}`);
    console.log(userTasks);
    // Отправка сообщения клиенту о запуске задачи
    socket.emit('taskStarted', task);

    // Запуск цикла задачи
    const taskInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const currentTime = moment();

      if (currentTime.isBefore(task.stopTime)) {
        console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} завершена ${new Date()}`);
        socket.emit('taskStarted', task);

        console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} запущена ${new Date()}`);
        socket.emit('taskCompleted', task);
      } else {
        console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} завершена по истечению времени ${new Date()}`);
        clearInterval(taskInterval);
        delete userTasks[userId];
        socket.emit('taskFinished', task);
      }
    }, duration * 60000);

    // Обработчик остановки задачи
    socket.on('stopTask', (taskId) => {
      // Удаление задачи из соответствующей структуры данных
      if (userTasks[userId] && userTasks[userId][nameTask]) {
        console.log(`Задача с id ${taskId} завершена принудительно ${new Date()}`);
        clearInterval(taskInterval);
        delete userTasks[userId];
        socket.emit('taskForceStopped', taskId);
      }
    });
  });

  // Обработчик отключения клиента
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Клиент отключился:', socket.id);
    // Получение userId из объекта socket
    const user = Object.keys(socket.rooms).find((room) => room !== socket.id);
    // Удаление информации о задачах пользователя при отключении
    if (userTasks[user]) {
      delete userTasks[user];
    }
  
    // Поиск и удаление соединения из хранилища по идентификатору пользователя
    const userId = Object.keys(userSockets).find((key) => userSockets[key] === socket);
    if (userId) {
      console.log(`Соединение ${socket.id} удалено из хранилища для пользователя ${userId}`);
    }
   
  });
  
});
```

index.html:

```
// Подключение к серверу WebSocket с сохраненным userId
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Подключено к серверу WebSocket');
      if (socket.recovered) {
        console.log('Соединение восстановлено:', socket.id);
        // Восстановление состояния сокета
        // Ваш код для обработки восстановленного состояния сокета
      } else {
        console.log('Новое подключение:', socket.id);
        // Ваш код для нового подключения
      }

      console.log("recovered?", socket.recovered);
/*
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (socket.io.engine) {
          // close the low-level connection and trigger a reconnection
          socket.io.engine.close();
        }
      }, 10000);*/
    });

    // Попытка восстановить соединение при обновлении страницы
    if (socket.connected) {
      console.log('Connection already established');
    } else {
      console.log('Attempting to reconnect');
      socket.connect();
    }
    // Обработчик запуска задачи
    function startTask(taskId) {
      const duration = document.getElementById(`duration${taskId}`).value;
      const stopAfter = document.getElementById(`stopAfter${taskId}`).value;
      const nameTask = document.getElementById(`nameTask${taskId}`).value;
      //const userId = document.getElementById('userId').value;

      socket.emit('startTask', {
        duration,
        stopAfter,
        nameTask,
        userId
      });
    }

    // Обработчик остановки задачи
    function stopTask(taskId) {
      socket.emit('stopTask', taskId);
    }

    // Обработчик запуска задачи на сервере
    socket.on('taskStarted', (task) => {
      console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} запущена ${new Date()}`);

    });

    // Обработчик завершения задачи на сервере
    socket.on('taskCompleted', (task) => {
      console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} завершена ${new Date()}`);
    });

    // Обработчик завершения задачи по истечению времени на сервере
    socket.on('taskFinished', (task) => {
      console.log(`Задача с id ${task.id} завершена по истечению времени ${new Date()}`);
    });

    // Обработчик принудительной остановки задачи на сервере
    socket.on('taskForceStopped', (taskId) => {
      console.log(`Задача с id ${taskId} завершена принудительно ${new Date()}`);
    });

    // Обработчик ошибки запуска задачи на сервере
    socket.on('taskError', (error) => {
      console.log('Ошибка запуска задачи:', error.message, ' ${new Date()}');
    });
```

Please help me to reconnect with socket after refreshing page or other way to output new messages in the console of the browser. Sorry for my English. Full Code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-AyA8UPqRpALAkjH-A9wDkkIstD3v2n9/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  Once you refresh the page, the old connection is gone forever.  The local socket is deleted, the server socket will be closed.  You can't "recover" it.  You will always create a new connection.  If there is a way for the client to identify itself, the server might be able to continue the work it was doing by using the new socket connection.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you write a code example please?

Comment: I did not understand how to use identification and a new socket to continue to perform the task and continue to display the result in the browser console

Comment: Well, how does the client identify itself?  Are you sending over any kind of identification?  How will you handle multiple clients?  It's POSSIBLE that the right answer is "don't do that" -- post a message saying "don't refresh me".  I'll post an answer with the alternative, but it's a big change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to support something like this, you need to start thinking more asynchronously.  You can't do all of the work in `startTask`, because as soon as you `emit` to a closed socket, it will stop.

You would need the server to have a global queue of tasks, independent of any connection.  When a "start" comes in, it adds something to the queue, and some master "task doer" starts handling the tasks, independent of the socket.  You will need to have the clients submit some kind of identification, similer to an HTTP cookie, otherwise there is simply no way for the server to tell whether an incoming connection is a new session, or a resumption of an old session.  Once you have that, you can have a "status" feed that reads the status from the global task queue.

If you're going to support this, you need to be prepared for every `emit` to fail, since that's what will happen if a browser refreshes.  All in all, it's likely that the BEST solution is to warn the user in large red letters not to do a refresh.